# ScriptDotNet Tasks

Tags: c#, task

I'm using ScriptDotNet as my scripting interface in my program.

I'm trying to return a value in a method only after setting it's response (halting the code until the input is given from the user), so I'm Tasks. More precisely, TaskCompletionSource of Boolean. Here's my method:

```
public TaskCompletionSource<bool> Response { get; private set; }

public Task<bool> SendYesNo()
    {
        this.Response = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        this.SendDialog(NpcMessageType.YesNo, this.Text);

        return this.Response.Task;
    }
```

The method `SendDialog` sends an input dialog to the client and halts the script. Once the client has sent an input response back, it sets the `Result` property of the `Response` variable based on the given input.

Now - to run the script asynchronously, I have to make the main method return a type of `Task` and include the `await` keyword before calling the method.

However, when I do `await SendYesNo();` ScriptDotNet doesn't recognize the await keyword, and when discluding the await keyword it doesn't even halt the script.

Any ideas how to solve this?